# XML to XML transform based on attribute value of previous sibling and ancestor to parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Note: Edited to make the elements and attribute values visible (they were invisible before because I used angle brackets) and to provide complete sample XML source file.

I'm trying to create XSL to do a complex XML to XML transform.

I have XML that has some text elements `<a:t>` which have various paths that 
start with either `/p:sld` or `/p:notes` but always end with
`/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t`.

These `<a:t>` elements need to be transformed into different target XML elements based on how the path starts and the attribute value of a (sometimes present) preceding sibling `<a:pPr>` to the `<a:r>` which is in turn parent to the `<a:t>`.

Here's a minimal version of the of the source XML for example: http://pastie.org/9559309

Here are the xpaths of the various `<a:t>` elements and the target XML for them. **Edit: I added a new item at the start of the items whose paths start `/p:notes`**

- xpath `/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t` to `<Body>`
- xpath `/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t` (`<a:r>` tag immediately preceded by `<a:pPr lvl="1">`) to `<Bulleted>`
- xpath `/p:sld/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t`  (`<a:r>` tag immediately preceded by `<a:pPr lvl="2">`) to `<Bulleted2>`
- xpath `/p:notes/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t`  to `<Body>`
- xpath `/p:notes/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t` (`<a:r>` tag immediately preceded by sibling `<a:pPr lvl="1">` ) to `<Body>`
- xpath `/p:notes/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t` (`<a:r>` tag immediately preceded by sibling `<a:pPr lvl="2">` ) to `<Bulleted>`
- xpath `/p:notes/p:cSld/p:spTree/p:sp/p:txBody/a:p/a:r/a:t` (`<a:r>` tag immediately preceded by sibling `<a:pPr lvl="3">` ) to `<Bulleted2>`

Note how it's the interaction of the start of the path and the attribute value of `<a:pPr>` when `<a:pPr>` is present that determines which xml element is output. For example:

Element `<a:t>` with a parent `<a:r>` that is immediately preceded by `<a:pPr "lvl=1">` should produce `<Bulleted>` if the source xpath starts `/p:sld` 
But if the source path starts `/p:notes` an `<a:t>` tag with everything else the same should be `<Body>` in the output.

Finally, I also need to transform a couple of elements near the root xpath `/p:notes` to `<PageBreak>` and xpath `/p:sld` to `<PageBreak>`.

The output XML should look like this. Edit: this now matches the content of the source xml.

```
<Document>
<PageBreak></PageBreak>
<bodytext>Activity 1:</bodytext>
<bodytext>Services Platform</bodytext>
<bodytext>Objective :</bodytext>
<Bulleted>The objective of this activity is to identify which services each node supports</Bulleted>
<bodytext>Description :</bodytext>
<Bulleted>This will be an individual activity. Using the information we just covered and the drawing on the next page fill in the table with the information requested by your Instructor</Bulleted>
<bodytext>IG: Mandatory individual activity. Time: 5 – 10 min.</bodytext>
<PageBreak></PageBreak> 
<bodytext>2</bodytext>
<bodytext>Activity 1: </bodytext>
<bodytext>Services Platform</bodytext>
<bodytext>To complete this activity, use the following material:</bodytext>
<Bulleted>The drawing and table on the next page, along with the information provided by your Instructor.</Bulleted>
</Document>
```

`<PageBreak>` is an empty element, `<bodytext>` and `<Bullet>` elements contain the text from the relevant `<a:t>` in the source XML, all other elements from the source XML are stripped.

UPDATE: I've written some xsl that seems like it should work to take the contents of each a:t element in the input xml and put the appropriate output element name around it on output. Body was changed to bodytext so that I don't get issues with body being a reserved html word.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//a:t/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:sld) > 0) and (count(ancestor::a:r[preceding-sibling[1]@lvl='1']) > 0">
                <bulleted><xsl:value-of select="."/></bulleted>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:sld) > 0) and (count(ancestor::a:r[preceding-sibling[1]@lvl='2']) > 0">
                <bulleted2><xsl:value-of select="."/></bulleted2>
            </xsl:when>         
            <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:notes) > 0) and (count(ancestor::a:r[preceding-sibling[1]@lvl='2']) > 0">
                <bulleted><xsl:value-of select="."/></bulleted>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(count(ancestor::p:notes) > 0) and (count(ancestor::a:r[preceding-sibling[1]@lvl='3']) > 0">
                <bulleted><xsl:value-of select="."/></bulleted>
            </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
                <bodytext><xsl:value-of select="."/></bodytext>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting syntax errors from Transform related to the fact that `a:t` uses a prefix that I'm not sure how to fix those errors.

I'm also not sure how to tell the Transform XSL processor to put a pagebreak on output where each p.sld or p.notes element appears on input and have those show up at the proper place. It seems like I should maybe make an outer "for-each /document/p.sld or /document/p.notes" command that

- outputs a `<pagebreak></pagebreak>` tag pair
- then starts another inside for-each `a:t` like in the code above, but limited to the scope of the `p.sld` or `p.notes` element currently selected by the outside for-each
- then closes the outside for-each command sending the processor to look for the next `p.sld` or `p.notes` in the source xml.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: How far have you got so far? Can you edit the question to show the current state of your XSLT?

Comment: Please post a minimal but **complete** example of the XML input, containing an instance of each case that needs to be handled, along with the expected XML output. -- Hint: reducing the problem to only two or three cases (and perhaps using less cryptic names) would be most beneficial. This is assuming you want to **learn** how to solve these issues, not have someone work them out for you.

Comment: I've been researching this for a while and only found the syntax for xml elements with following siblings of that element and for elements with atttributes. I don't see how to connect the two or what the syntax for prior sibling of a parent is. I have edited to add link to minimal xml source and fixed errors that hid part of my original post because I put element names in angle brackets. I'm still learning XSLT and this is my first question here.

Comment: @ShayneWeyker If I were teaching XSLT I don't think I would let students loose on this problem until about week 4, so I sympathise. I've been doing XSLT for 15 years, but it would still take me an hour or two to understand the task. Try to create a simpler problem that captures the essence of it.

Comment: As with any programming problem, breaking it down into pieces and solve one at a time may be helpful -- you may have to rewrite some of that when you see how those pieces interact, but it's a lot easier to debug something that's mostly right than to "debug a blank sheet of paper". You probably either need to learn about the reverse axes (parent and ancestor) and have predicates that search upward from these nodes, or you need to have the higher-level stuff set modes on the way down which will condition how the lower-level items are processed.

Comment: Oh, and "immediately preceeding" is a combination of preceding-sibling and a positional predicate [1] to say that you only want the first such (searching backward since it's a reverse axis).

Comment: @IanRoberts I have now added piece of slt code that looks like it will solve much of the problem once I can resolve the issues discussed at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Pastie says that the content has been removed.